Moduli space of n ordered points on affine line up to automorphism
I am interested in the space of $n$ ordered points on the affine line $\mathbb{A}^1$, modulo the automorphism group $Aut(\mathbb{A}^1) \cong \mathbb{A}^1 \rtimes \mathbb{G}_m$.
Question Does this quotient exist in some meaningful sense? Is there any nice model of this space? Is there any reference for questions along this line?
My background I am not familiar with GIT, and my vague impression for GIT is that quotients by reductive group is handlable; however $Aut(\mathbb{A}^1)$ is not reductive. I am not sure if this space can be thought of as Spec of invariant-functions on $\mathbb{A}^1$ for example.
Any reference/help is appreciated. Thanks!

They are allowed to repeat. Ah you are right! Good point about using the first coordinate to kill the unipotent part. If you write it as an answer I will accept it. Thanks!

Also as a quick follow up - one motivation of this question is to find a model which is symmetric in the $n$ points. Specifying one coordinate breaks this symmetry - is there any remedy?

Performing the change of coordinates $(x_1, \dots, x_n) \mapsto (x_1, x_2 - x_1, \dots, x_n - x_1)$, the translation action of $\mathbb{G}_a \cong \mathbb{A}^1$ is only on the first coordinate, and is of course free transitive there. Therefore the entire quotient is isomorphic (in whatever sense) to $\mathbb{A}^{n-1}/\mathbb{G}_m$ (where the action is by multiplication on each coordinate).
If you want to keep track of the action of the symmetric group $S_n$, this $\mathbb{A}^{n-1}$ is isomorphic to a copy of the "fundamental" irreducible representation (and the above change of coordinates is decomposing the defining permutation representation into irreducibles).
